# Can't connect to postgres Scala slick org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed

Tags: java, postgresql, scala, jdbc, slick

Can't connect to postgres from scala slick app, jdbc connection on VPS.
But I can connect

- from local computer to VPS using dbeaver,
- and I can connect using `psql localhost` from inside VPS,
- and I can connect to VPS db launching app on my home computer.

So looks like everything working except app on VPS. Port is open, configs are same, Java version 1.8 on home computer and vps, connection string not empty and looks like

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:{custom port}/{db_name}
```

Error log:

```
DEBUG c.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - database.whale - Cannot acquire connection from data source
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:292)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:211)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$100(HikariPool.java:71)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:706)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:692)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:75)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually restart the VPS make all working.

I tried to restart firewalls(ufw, iptables etc), postgres, apps, another components, nothing happend. But restart full VPS save the day.
I think it was like a bug in OS, but don't know what kind of...